# React Native CameraRoll.getPhotos return the "uri" cannot upload in Web API

Tags: c#, react-native, asp.net-web-api, image-upload, camera-roll

CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams)
      .then((data) => this._appendImages(data), (e) => console.log(e));

[image]

when i use FormData

```
const images = messages.map(k => {
    return {
        uri: k.image,   //`file:///${k.image}`,
        name: k.filename,
        type: mime.lookup(k.filename),
    }
})

console.log(images)

postData = new FormData();
postData.append('file', images);
postData.append('userid', this.user._id);
postData.append('time', moment().format('YYYY-M-D H:mm:ss'));
postData.append('group', this.groupID);

axios.post(WebAPI.url.chat.postImage,
    postData,
    {
        headers: {
            access_token: this.user.access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
    }
).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

C# can get the Request.Form, but can not get the Request.Files

[image]

who can help me ? thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

oh! my fault ！

postData.append('file', images);     **// append file must be one by one**

so change to this , will work well !

```
messages.forEach(k => {
    postData.append('file', {
        uri: k.image,
        name: k.filename,
        type: mime.lookup(k.filename),
    });
})
```